# SQL: How to spread values across columns without a cursor, with running totals?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cumulative-sum

I have 3 registrations:

```
ID      RegisteredHours
1       7                   
2       11                  
3       6
```

The hours 7, 11 and 6 should be split or divided between Holidays, WorkHours and Nights according to the rules:

1. Holidays <= 6 hours
2. WorkHours <= 11 hours
3. Nights <= 7 hours

First Holidays should be filled, then WorkHours and then Nights.
The expected result is this:

```
ID  RegisteredHours     Holidays    WorkHours       Nights      [Comment]
1   7                   6           1               0           6 hours of 7 can go to Holidays so the remaining 1 hour goes to WorkHours. Holidays are now filled (Sum=6).
2   11                  0           10              1           10 hours of 11 can go to WorkHours so the remaining 1 hour goes to Nights. WorkHours are now filled (Sum=11).
3   6                   0           0               6           All 6 hours can go to Nights. Nights are now filled (Sum=7)
```

How to calculate that without using a cursor and using running totals? Here is the code to continue:

```
if object_id('Regs') is not null drop table Regs
go

create table Regs
(
    ID int,
    RegisteredHours int
)
insert into Regs values (1, 7)
insert into Regs values (2, 1)
insert into Regs values (3, 6)

select  *,
        6 HolidayHoursMax,
        11 WorkHoursMax,
        7 NightsHoursMax
from Regs r
```

Comment: This should be possible via some CASE... but is it possible there is something wrong with your example? Your first 7 hours are NOT <= 6, so they should go to Workhours... However, if the rule says "6 hours Holiday, remaining 1 hour Workhour" the second example looks out of place: Why isn't it "6 hours Holiday, remaining 5 hours workhours"? And then why are the last 6 hours written to Nights and not to Holidays if "<= 6" means Holiday?

Comment: The remaining 1 hour goes to WorkHours because 7-6=1. And 1 hour goes to Nights because 11-10=1

Comment: We are dividing the first column between the next 3 columns.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood you when reading the original post. However, please find my solution attached - at least with the provided testcases (and the ones I added) I could't see any violations of the rules provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the desired results. You'll want to test against a larger data set and adjust according to the results...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Regs', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Regs;

CREATE TABLE #Regs (
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    RegisteredHours INT NOT NULL 
    );

INSERT #Regs (ID, RegisteredHours) VALUES
    (1, 7), (2, 11), (3, 6);

--  SELECT * FROM #Regs r

--========================================

SELECT 
    r.ID,
    r.RegisteredHours,
    Holidays = CASE 
                    WHEN r.ID = 1 AND r.RegisteredHours <= 6 THEN r.RegisteredHours 
                    WHEN r.ID = 1 AND r.RegisteredHours > 6 THEN 6
                    ELSE 0
                END,
    WorkHours = CASE
                    WHEN r.ID = 1 AND r.RegisteredHours BETWEEN 7 AND 16 THEN r.RegisteredHours - 6
                    WHEN r.ID = 1 AND r.RegisteredHours > 16 THEN 10
                    WHEN r.ID = 2 AND r.RegisteredHours <= 10 THEN r.RegisteredHours
                    WHEN r.ID = 2 AND r.RegisteredHours > 10 THEN 10
                    ELSE 0
                END,
    Nights =    CASE 
                    WHEN r.ID = 1 AND r.RegisteredHours > 16 THEN r.RegisteredHours - 16
                    WHEN r.ID = 2 AND r.RegisteredHours > 10 THEN r.RegisteredHours - 10
                    WHEN r.ID = 3 THEN r.RegisteredHours
                    ELSE 0
                END 
FROM 
    #Regs r;
```

Comment: It is not good to write `"ID = 1", "ID = 2"` because I have thousands of IDs.

Comment: The post a representative sample of data an supply a set of rules that can be used.

Comment: I think the idea is to have a flexible solution: It should work with any number of IDs and with variable threshholds per hour type... therefore any hardcoded approach might not lead to the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following solution. Maybe it could be implemented with less CTEs, but at least at first glance it produced the same result as you presumed plus it is flexible concerning Number of ID's etc.:

```
DECLARE @Regs TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    RegisteredHours int
)

insert into @Regs values (7);
insert into @Regs values (11);
insert into @Regs values (6);

insert into @Regs values (2);
insert into @Regs values (1);
insert into @Regs values (3);
insert into @Regs values (1);
insert into @Regs values (1);
insert into @Regs values (7);
insert into @Regs values (5);
insert into @Regs values (1);
insert into @Regs values (4);
insert into @Regs values (3);


DECLARE @HolidayHoursMax int = 6;
DECLARE @WorkHoursMax int = 11;
DECLARE @NightHoursMax int = 7;

WITH cteHolidayBasis AS(
  SELECT r.ID
        ,r.RegisteredHours
        ,SUM(CASE
               WHEN r.RegisteredHours <= @HolidayHoursMax THEN r.RegisteredHours
               ELSE @HolidayHoursMax
             END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS HolidayHours
        ,@HolidayHoursMax - SUM(CASE
                                  WHEN r.RegisteredHours <= @HolidayHoursMax THEN r.RegisteredHours
                                  ELSE @HolidayHoursMax
                                END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS HolidayHoursRem
    FROM @Regs r
),
cteHoliday AS(
  SELECT  ID
         ,CASE
            WHEN (HolidayHoursRem = 0) AND (RegisteredHours > @HolidayHoursMax) THEN @HolidayHoursMax
            WHEN (HolidayHoursRem = 0) AND (RegisteredHours <= @HolidayHoursMax) THEN RegisteredHours
            WHEN (HolidayHoursRem > 0) THEN RegisteredHours
            WHEN (HolidayHoursRem < 0 AND LAG(HolidayHoursRem) OVER (ORDER BY ID) > 0) THEN LAG(HolidayHoursRem) OVER (ORDER BY ID)
            ELSE 0
          END AS HolidayHours
         ,RegisteredHours - CASE
                               WHEN (HolidayHoursRem = 0) AND (RegisteredHours > @HolidayHoursMax) THEN @HolidayHoursMax
                               WHEN (HolidayHoursRem = 0) AND (RegisteredHours <= @HolidayHoursMax) THEN RegisteredHours
                               WHEN (HolidayHoursRem > 0) THEN RegisteredHours
                               WHEN (HolidayHoursRem < 0 AND LAG(HolidayHoursRem) OVER (ORDER BY ID) > 0) THEN LAG(HolidayHoursRem) OVER (ORDER BY ID)
                               ELSE 0
                            END AS RemHours
    FROM cteHolidayBasis
),
cteWorkBasis AS(
  SELECT ID
        ,RemHours
        ,SUM(CASE
               WHEN RemHours <= @WorkHoursMax THEN RemHours
               ELSE @WorkHoursMax
             END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS WorkHours
        ,@WorkHoursMax - SUM(CASE
                               WHEN RemHours <= @WorkHoursMax THEN RemHours
                               ELSE @WorkHoursMax
                             END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS WorkHoursRem
    FROM cteHoliday
),
cteWork AS(
  SELECT  ID
         ,CASE
            WHEN (WorkHoursRem = 0) AND (RemHours > @WorkHoursMax) THEN @WorkHoursMax
            WHEN (WorkHoursRem = 0) AND (RemHours <= @WorkHoursMax) THEN RemHours
            WHEN (WorkHoursRem > 0) THEN RemHours
            WHEN (WorkHoursRem < 0 AND LAG(WorkHoursRem) OVER (ORDER BY ID) > 0) THEN LAG(WorkHoursRem) OVER (ORDER BY ID)
            ELSE 0
          END AS WorkHours
         ,RemHours - CASE
                       WHEN (WorkHoursRem = 0) AND (RemHours > @WorkHoursMax) THEN @WorkHoursMax
                       WHEN (WorkHoursRem = 0) AND (RemHours <= @WorkHoursMax) THEN RemHours
                       WHEN (WorkHoursRem > 0) THEN RemHours
                       WHEN (WorkHoursRem < 0 AND LAG(WorkHoursRem) OVER (ORDER BY ID) > 0) THEN LAG(WorkHoursRem) OVER (ORDER BY ID)
                       ELSE 0
                     END AS RemHours
    FROM cteWorkBasis
),
cteNightBasis AS(
  SELECT ID
        ,RemHours
        ,SUM(CASE
               WHEN RemHours <= @NightHoursMax THEN RemHours
               ELSE @NightHoursMax
             END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS NightHours
        ,@NightHoursMax - SUM(CASE
                                 WHEN RemHours <= @NightHoursMax THEN RemHours
                                 ELSE @NightHoursMax
                               END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS NightHoursRem
    FROM cteWork
),
cteNight AS(
  SELECT  ID
         ,CASE
            WHEN (NightHoursRem = 0) AND (RemHours > @NightHoursMax) THEN @NightHoursMax
            WHEN (NightHoursRem = 0) AND (RemHours <= @NightHoursMax) THEN RemHours
            WHEN (NightHoursRem > 0) THEN RemHours
            WHEN (NightHoursRem < 0 AND LAG(NightHoursRem) OVER (ORDER BY ID) > 0) THEN LAG(NightHoursRem) OVER (ORDER BY ID)
            ELSE 0
          END AS NightHours
         ,RemHours - CASE
                       WHEN (NightHoursRem = 0) AND (RemHours > @NightHoursMax) THEN @NightHoursMax
                       WHEN (NightHoursRem = 0) AND (RemHours <= @NightHoursMax) THEN RemHours
                       WHEN (NightHoursRem > 0) THEN RemHours
                       WHEN (NightHoursRem < 0 AND LAG(NightHoursRem) OVER (ORDER BY ID) > 0) THEN LAG(NightHoursRem) OVER (ORDER BY ID)
                       ELSE 0
                     END AS RemHours
    FROM cteNightBasis
)
SELECT R.ID
      ,R.RegisteredHours
      ,cH.HolidayHours
      ,cW.WorkHours
      ,cN.NightHours
      ,cN.RemHours
  FROM @Regs AS R
  JOIN cteHoliday AS cH ON R.ID = cH.ID
  JOIN cteWork AS cW ON R.ID = cW.ID
  JOIN cteNight AS cN ON R.ID = cN.ID
ORDER BY R.ID
```

I added another column "RemHours" in the output - in case you exceed the total number of hours from MaxWork + MaxHoliday + MaxNight. Furthermore I added several more testcases - just comment the first three inserts in order to test with smaller values.